# Draw random samples from a custom (Epanechnikov) function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I would like to draw random samples from a continuous custom function.

In this case I am interested to draw from the [`Epanechnikov`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Kernel_functions_in_common_use) function:

How can I do this in `pandas / numpy / scipy / scikit-learn`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random numbers with a given probably density function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471457/generating-random-numbers-with-a-given-probably-density-function)

Answer (score 1):

In a general case, as comments indicate, you should subclass `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` and provide your subclass with `_pdf` et al.

In this particular case, you're looking for `scipy.stats.rdist` with `c=4`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rdist.html