# Draw random selection of a numpy array following approximately a lognormal distribution

Tags: python, random, distribution

Suppose I have a grid of numbers in Python that I have created using

```
import numpy as np
h = np.linspace(0,20,100)
```

I am trying to make a random selection within the elements of `h` in a way that the distribution of the selections follows for example the log-normal distribution, with a given mean and standard deviation. How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be easier to just draw samples from a lognormal distribution

```
np.random.lognormal(mean=5,sigma=2,size=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved very fast. At first you have to find a way to draw random indices following your custom `pdf`. After you have done this, you can use these indices to draw numbers from `0` to `100` and return the entries of the array at these indices.

To draw the numbers randomly in this way, there are a few ways in ´python´, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471457/generating-random-numbers-with-a-given-probably-density-function) for example. When you have drawn your random indices in this way in an array called `indices` you can use:

```
result = h[indices]
```

to create your desired numpy array.